# how to enable Notification Listener without restart the device

Tags: android

I just enabled Notification Access permission to my app. But the Notification Listener starts Only I restart the device.How can I enable the service once my app gets installed?

Answer (score -1):

You have to register a receiver in your AndroidManifest.xml.
Like below (This is an example of the GCM listener for Google Cloud Messaging)

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Let me know if you need more info. But I assume you know how this works since you seem to have implemented the

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

        </intent-filter>
```

Can you share you **AndroidManifest.xml**?

Comment: Sorry, your given example is different that is using GCM. But I just implemented Services and broad cast receiver

Comment: <service android:name="com.hiox.wholovesme.NLService"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>